# How to best select the correct element (Python 3, Selenium)

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to select a particular element from a page using Python 3 and Selenium.

The page consists of a long list (hundreds of items) that are all formatted just like this:

[image]

The html for this table looks like this:

[image]

And when I expand the element for the particular item I'm trying to click on, it looks like this (link obscured for privacy):

[image]

What I have been doing so far is to search for the element I need using

```
titleField = 'Zombie Apocalypse'   
searchBuilder = "//*[contains(text(), '" + titleField + "')]"
searchForBook = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(searchBuilder)
searchForBook[0].click()
```

which works some of the time.  I'm running into problems when there are two items with that same name, or if there is an apostrophe in the title, and sometimes I can't figure out why it didn't work at all.

Is there a better way to select an individual element out of that table than the way I'm using?  I will have the title of the item ahead of time, but not the ID number.  The ID number is the information I'm trying to scrape.

I'm also okay with it if the search returns the URL of the item, because the ID number is contained in that URL, so I can just pull it from there.  But the title isn't in the URL, so I didn't know how to search for it.

Comment: It might be possible to just scrape for an ID number field inside of the table? This way you get all of the ID numbers plus it seems relatively consistent. Unless you are looking for specific items, which then I would suggest just grabbing each url in the table and getting its name field to compare against your own.

Comment: That's an idea.  With the table set up the way it is, how would I get the name field for each URL?  All I need is the ID number, but it does need to be for a specific item.

Comment: When there are two or more items with the same name, which one do you want to click, or do you want to click both?

Comment: Also does @glenfant [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45888932/6476044)  solve your issue with quotes (apostrophes)?

Comment: The name is after the href, "Zombie Apocolapyse" maybe store the whole href as an object and if the text field matches then scrape the ID?

Comment: A link to the page and a better description of what you actually want would help. You said you want the ID but you aren't scraping the ID in your code, you are clicking on a link. Please clarify the ultimate goal.

Comment: I can't give you a link to the page because it's a person's private website behind a password.  I'm clicking the link because from there it was a simple matter of getting the ID out of the page's URL once it had been clicked.  The ID is my ultimate goal.

Comment: And to clarify the other question, when two or more items have the same name, I'd need the one with the higher ID number.  But I don't know if there is a way to specify that before it's clicked, so I suppose probably both should be selected and then I can compare.  The quote solution did not work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You should quote the text before inserting it in the XPath expression. This will encode appropriately yoyr string for xpath expressions. Note that "quoteattr"ed stings include surrounding `'`or `"`.

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import quoteattr
titleField = quoteattr('Zombie Apocalypse')  # But may contain XML markup chars
searchBuilder = "//*[contains(text(), " + titleField + ")]"
searchForBook = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(searchBuilder)
searchForBook[0].click()
```

Comment: I'm not at my computer right now, but as soon as I am, I will give you the error message this gives me.  This might be kind of on the right track.